# Exact regex preg_replace with special character

Tags: php, regex

I need to pass a string with hash and change the value by another value. I am trying the following code:

```
$formula = "ARRED(((CAT(#AVSIM#+#AV#AT8+#AV#ATD+#AV#SIM+#AT))+#AV#SIMB);0.25;D)+0";

$formula = preg_replace('~(#AV#SIMB)([^\w]|$)~i', "Found", $formula);

RESULT = ARREDD(((QTDCAT2(#AVSIM#+#AV#AT8+#AV#ATD+#AV#SIM+#AT))+Found;0.25;D)+0
```

But it removes the next caracter in string, how I can change this? I need a regex that removes only the value passed with the special character `#`

Answer (score 2):

You actually capture that char with `([^\w]|$)` (= `(\W|$)`) capturing group. So, to keep it in the result, you need to add thr `$2` placeholder into the replacement pattern:

```
$formula = preg_replace('~(#AV#SIMB)([^\w]|$)~i', 'Found$2', $formula);
```

Else, use an equivalent non-consuming pattern, a word boundary:

```
$formula = preg_replace('~#AV#SIMB\b~i', 'Found', $formula);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/9oGkWs):

```
$formula = "ARRED(((CAT(#AVSIM#+#AV#AT8+#AV#ATD+#AV#SIM+#AT))+#AV#SIMB);0.25;D)+0";
echo preg_replace('~(#AV#SIMB)([^\w]|$)~i', 'Found$2', $formula) . "\n";
echo preg_replace('~(#AV#SIMB)\b~i', 'Found', $formula);
// => ARRED(((CAT(#AVSIM#+#AV#AT8+#AV#ATD+#AV#SIM+#AT))+Found);0.25;D)+0
// => ARRED(((CAT(#AVSIM#+#AV#AT8+#AV#ATD+#AV#SIM+#AT))+Found);0.25;D)+0
```

Comment: @Diegojj As you see in my example, they both should work unless you have a pattern other than the one you used. In case the `SIMB` ends with a non-word char, then yes, `\b` won't work. If `SIMB` ends with a word char, `\b` will work as after a word char, `\b` matches a position before a non-word char or end of string.